# IOS Getting location updates when app terminated without using significantChange

Tags: ios, background, cllocation, terminate

I apologise for the redundancy of this topic, but in spite all the given answers, I can't identify the possibility of getting accuracyBest location updates when the app is terminated. 
I don't want to use monitoringSignificantChange, I want the best possible accuracy; I won't submit the app on the AppStore, so Apple restrictions are not a problem either.

I have gone through these:

-[Location update even when app is killed/terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527972/location-update-even-when-app-is-killed-terminated)

-[iOS update location even when app is terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788865/ios-update-location-even-when-app-is-terminated)

-[Working with location updates when app is terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589592/working-with-location-updates-when-app-is-terminated)

-http://mobileoop.com/getting-location-updates-for-ios-7-and-8-when-the-app-is-killedterminatedsuspended

and many more, but it is not clear whereas it's possible or not. I currently have my project, everything works great with significantChange but I now need better accuracy.

Could somebody tell me straight forward if getting best accuracy location update when app is killed is possible please ?

Thank you infinitely,

Comment: Yes you can, but you may need to combine it with significant location monitoring in order to get continuous location updates; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20187700/startupdatelocations-in-background-didupdatingtolocation-only-called-10-20-time

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at the below content from the Apple doc, you clearly have 2 alternatives against using significant location changes to wake a app from the background. **I have marked in bold the services you can use to relaunch the app if it has been terminated.**

> Using Location Services in the Background Most location services are
>   meant to be used while your app is in the foreground but some can also
>   run in the background. In some cases, location events can even cause
>   your app to be relaunched to process an event. To run most location
>   services in the background, you need to enable the location updates
>   background mode in the Capabilities tab of your Xcode project. For
>   services that launch your app, you need to request (and be granted)
>   “Always” authorization from the user.
>
> The standard location service delivers events normally while an app is
>   running in the foreground. When your app is in the background, this
>   service delivers events only when the location-updates background mode
>   is enabled for the app. This service does not relaunch iOS apps that
>   have been terminated.
>
> The **significant location change service** delivers events normally
>   while an app is running in the foreground or background. **For a
>   terminated iOS app, this service relaunches the app to deliver
>   events.** Use of this service requires “Always” authorization from the
>   user.
>
> The **region monitoring service** delivers events normally while an
>   app is running in the foreground or background. (You can use this
>   service for both geographic and beacon regions.) **For a terminated
>   iOS app, this service relaunches the app to deliver events.** Use of
>   this service requires “Always” authorization from the user.
>
> Beacon ranging delivers events normally while an app is running in the
>   foreground. When your app is in the background, this service delivers
>   events only when the location-updates background mode is enabled for
>   the app and the standard location service is running. (If the beacon
>   region’s notifyEntryStateOnDisplay property is YES, waking the device
>   causes the app to range for beacons for a few seconds in the
>   background.) This service does not relaunch iOS apps that have been
>   terminated; however, you can be relaunched by monitoring beacon
>   regions using the region monitoring service.
>
> The heading service delivers events normally while an iOS app is
>   running in the foreground. When your app is in the background, this
>   service delivers events only when the location-updates background mode
>   is enabled for the app and the standard location service is running.
>   This service does not relaunch iOS apps that have been terminated.
>
> The **visit service** delivers events normally while an iOS app is
>   running in the foreground. When your app is in the background, this
>   service delivers events only when the location-updates background mode
>   is enabled for the app and the standard location service is running.
>   **For a terminated iOS app, this service relaunches the app to deliver events.** Use of this service requires “Always” authorization from the
>   user.
>
> Enabling the location-updates background mode ensures that an app
>   continues to receive location events while in the background. When the
>   app moves to the background, the system adds the location-services
>   indicator to the status bar to let the user know that an app is using
>   location services. The system may still terminate the app at any time
>   to reclaim its memory or other resources.
>
> Also from the doc,
>
> Getting the Visited Locations
>   **In iOS, the visits service provides an alternative to the significant location change service for apps that need location
>   information about interesting places that the user visited.** For
>   example, if the user is in one location for an extended period of
>   time, the service might generate an event when the user arrives at
>   that location and another when the user leaves that location. The
>   service is intended for apps that might already be using the
>   significant location change service and want an even lower power way
>   to do so. You would not use this service to create navigation apps or
>   apps that rely on regular location updates.

Document Link:

> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW73

Comment: Thanks a lot... So no alternatives to the visit service or the region monitoring. I was looking at getting continuous location updates while the app is killed. But I understand that Apple restricts it to events only.

Comment: I am doing the same but strangely, the wake up timings of my app varies across OS versions and devices, even with the same code base. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50250239/ios-uiapplicationlaunchoptionslocationkey-is-fired-at-different-times-across-mul

Answer (score 4):

Continuous location updates stop  when your app is terminated.

Geo-fence notices will re-launch your app even if it's not running. I think a significant location change will also relaunch you're app but I'm not as sure about that.

Once you're relaunched you can start location updates again with the accuracy set to best like you want, but I think you're going to need to use one of those two APIs to get relaunched again after you've been terminated.

Comment: I am doing the same but strangely, the wake up timings of my app varies across OS versions and devices, even with the same code base. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50250239/ios-uiapplicationlaunchoptionslocationkey-is-fired-at-different-times-across-mul