# How to get location updates in iOS even if the app is in terminated state or is killed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I searched a lot for one week. I searched google for the same question and I was able to get something working. But location updates don't work for the suspended state. It only works for foreground and background states.

And I need location updates after terminated state also.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]. You should update accordingly. You have to show some efforts. What have you tried, some code, etc.

Comment: You can get "The significant location change service",
Check this answer
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450524/ios-getting-location-updates-when-app-terminated-without-using-significantchange"
Or read this...
 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW73

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [applicationWillTerminate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate)

By Apple documentation it says:

> This method lets your app know that it is about to be terminated and
>   purged from memory entirely. You should use this method to perform any
>   final clean-up tasks for your app, such as freeing shared resources,
>   saving user data, and invalidating timers. Your implementation of this
>   method has approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return.
>   If the method does not return before time expires, the system may kill
>   the process altogether. For apps that do not support background
>   execution or are linked against iOS 3.x or earlier, this method is
>   always called when the user quits the app. For apps that support
>   background execution, this method is generally not called when the
>   user quits the app because the app simply moves to the background in
>   that case. However, this method may be called in situations where the
>   app is running in the background (not suspended) and the system needs
>   to terminate it for some reason. After calling this method, the app
>   also posts a UIApplicationWillTerminate notification to give
>   interested objects a chance to respond to the transition.

If you want to have user's location when app is not in memory, short answer: **Impossible**.

Comment: Still , i did not get any location updates while iphone terminated? any one have code Please send me?

Comment: locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
                locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
                locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()  You also have to set certain keys in the plist file and request authorization etc.