# Location Update while app is terminated

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

I wanted to get user location updates when the app gets terminated.

What I tried:
In AppDelegate:

```
var locationManger: CLLocationManager!
```

In the applicationDidFinishLaunching

```
setupLocationManager()
```

And also in AppDelegate:

```
@nonobjc func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        locationManger.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }
func setupLocationManager(){
        locationManger = CLLocationManager()
        locationManger.delegate = self
        locationManger.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManger.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .inactive{
            let notification = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            notification.title = "Location Update"
            notification.body = "updated in background"

            let notificationTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "locationUpdate", content: notification, trigger: notificationTrigger)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
        }

    }
```

But i dont get a push notification...
Any ideas?
Referring to this post: [IOS Getting location updates when app terminated without using significantChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450524/ios-getting-location-updates-when-app-terminated-without-using-significantchange?noredirect=1&lq=1) it should be possible

Comment: have you turned on background location fetch?

Comment: Yes if you mean in Project Settings -> Capabilities -> Background Mode Location Updates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Get Location Updates for iOS 7 and 8 Even when the App is Suspended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742677/how-to-get-location-updates-for-ios-7-and-8-even-when-the-app-is-suspended)

Comment: @markus-g : As per the link you shared it looks like it is possible to get background location update if app is terminated. Please decline the accepted answer as it is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling background fetch here?
[image]

Comment: where to find this window?

Comment: This is Edit Scheme. So, on top left of Xcode you will see target, from there you can select edit scheme from drop down