# Fetch user location in terminated state (Even in background) for find the nearby user

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on dating app, In which match(Male/Female) will be done when they will crossed each other by 20 meter radius. **Same as Happen App**.

The Approach i have used **startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges** and **regionMonitoring**.
With creating region and implement these delegate

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
print("Entered Region")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
print("Exited Region")
locationManager?.stopMonitoring(for: region)
//Start location manager and fetch current location
locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
 }
```

But finally, Want to get a solution for someone other user, When he/she will cross me.

Note : App is running or not running. This thing dosen't make any sense. App should be work on terminated state also.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450524/ios-getting-location-updates-when-app-terminated-without-using-significantchange

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IOS Getting location updates when app terminated without using significantChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450524/ios-getting-location-updates-when-app-terminated-without-using-significantchange)

Comment: @Adobels

That is right but i am not getting the mean for this line. Please explain if you know in brief.

The significant location change service delivers events normally while an app is running in the foreground or background. For a terminated iOS app, this service relaunches the app to deliver events.